# Can I send Elmah erros details to ApplicationInsights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, elmah

I have an old application which I used **Elmah** to aggregate exceptions and save data to disk/db.

Today, I start using Azure Monitor with **Application insights SDK** to monitor my services, so that I'm asking how can I keep using Elmah and send my application error details to Azure monitor too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple but effective hack is to use the [Error Filter](https://elmah.github.io/a/error-filtering/#filtering-programmatically) feature to intercept the exceptions routed to ELMAH and send them to App Insights as well:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
     new TelemetryClient().TrackException(e.Exception);
}
```

Not that you should reuse an instance of `TelemetryClient` but this code is just to give you an idea of the approach.

Comment: How would this work in a .Net Core or .Net 5 blazor app where there is no Global.asax file?